# Not able to set background color

Tags: html, css

I am not able to set the background color for the `#widgetContainer` div. I was wondering if  there is a way to align the div so that the empty space left out while floating an element can be minimized?

My Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/rLzb0caq](http://jsfiddle.net/rLzb0caq)

Comment: Can you please post the js fiddle

Comment: Yeah i have updated it.

Comment: Please post a fiddle that is necessary your fiddle is too confusing and even your question isn't explained properly

Comment: You're welcome, remember that voting up on accepted answers is regarded as a good practice. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #widgetContainer has no height because all elements are floating. You should set the background color of #widgetContent instead, to get the desired result.

```
#widgetContent {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px groove solid red;
    outline: 2px solid black;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/inuya5ha/8ef7Lsvt/

Answer (score 0):

Change `#widgetContent` class to

```
#widgetContent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCC;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 2px solid black;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: #widgetContainer pops out of the parent container. I need it to look like a widget where it has head and body.

Comment: change `#widgetContent` class. I edited my answer. check. Add background to `#widgetContent`

Answer (score 0):

Insert this tag before closing tag of #widgetContainer :

```
<span style="clear: both; display: block;"></span>
```

This will clear the floating of elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want background color to `widgetContainer` div, add `overflow:hidden` to `#widgetContainer`

```css
#widgetContent {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px groove solid red;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
#widgetHead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
}
#widgetContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#widgetContainer > div {
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
  min-height: 75px;
  margin: 1%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px -7px 12px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px -7px 12px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 6px -7px 12px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 0.25% solid;
}
#widgetContainer > div div {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 75px;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 2% auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px -7px 12px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px -7px 12px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 6px -7px 12px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 0.25% solid black;
}
.clean {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="widgetContent">

  <div id="widgetHead">
    widgetData
  </div>
  <div id="widgetContainer">


    <div id="node1" style="background-color: red;">
      node1
      <div id="vip1" style="background-color: red;">
        vip1
        <div id="obj1" style="background-color: gray;">
          obj1
        </div>
        <div id="obj2" style="background-color: green;">
          obj2
        </div>
        <div id="obj3" style="background-color: green;">
          obj3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="vip2" style="background-color: blue;">
        vip2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="node2">
      node2
      <div id="vip1" style="background-color: green;">
        vip1
      </div>
      <div id="vip2" style="background-color: green;">
        vip2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="node3" style="background-color: red;">
      node3
    </div>
    <div id="node4" style="background-color: red;">
      node4
    </div>
    <div id="node5" style="background-color: red;">
      node5
    </div>
    <div id="node6" style="background-color: red;">
      node6
    </div>
    <div id="node7" style="background-color: red;">
      node7
    </div>
    <div id="node8" style="background-color: red;">
      node8
    </div>
    <div id="node1" style="background-color: red;">
      node1
      <div id="vip1" style="background-color: red;">
        vip1
        <div id="obj1" style="background-color: gray;">
          obj1
        </div>
        <div id="obj2" style="background-color: green;">
          obj2
        </div>
        <div id="obj3" style="background-color: green;">
          obj3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="vip2" style="background-color: blue;">
        vip2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clean cf">
  </div>
</div>
```